# Python3 Dynamic bug reporting

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic

Our team in ERIAN are transferring and developing codes in python 3.4.1. As I tried to test dynamic properties in python3, I am stunned at the following dynamic errors, which other programmers should pay attention to:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

''' Created on 12 Sep, 2014

@author: wang yi/lei, Singapore '''

class foo(object):   
    dic = {}
    def __init__(self):
        print('self:', self)
        self.dic[self.__str__()] = "foo"

    def __go__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'foo'

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(bar, self).__init__()
        print('self', self)
        print(self.dic)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'bar'    

# Comment others, when you test one case
if __name__ == '__main__':
# test case 1: python will output parameters as expected    
    f = foo()      ## self: foo
    f.__go__(bar)  ## self: bar \n self bar \n {'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'} #wrong !!!

# test case 2: python will output parameters as expected    
    b = bar() # self: bar \n self bar \n {'bar':'foo'}

# test case 3: python will go wrong! i.e. b will be associated an unexpected keyword pair 'foo':'foo'
    f = foo()  ## self: foo
    b = bar()  ## self: bar \n self: bar \n self bar \n {'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'} #wrong!!!
    pass
```

I think this result is not what people need in reality. You need a property not associated with super class objects (public domain), do you? Some people argues with his or her identity testing proof, which is convincing that I was actually declaring a class property, but what makes things trick is I didn't employ '@static' decorator. It is ridiculous to some extend.

People should not test my test cases **simultaneously**!

Comment: As an aside, you should not create your own custom methods with the format `__method__`. Methods that begin and end with two underscores are reserved for use by Python itself.

Comment: @dano we should discuss this problem again, with my new codes see below:

Comment: @dano, foo bar should be different classes, your localised solution means every object of each class will preserve a local copy. This is not what I wanted. I want the property shared by the objects of "exactly" the same class not two "similar " classes

Comment: Sorry, Wang. Perhaps because of the language barrier, it wasn't clear to me that you *wanted* the state to be shared between all instances of the class. It seems you've figured out how to address that use-case on your own, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're making `dic` a class variable instead of an instance variable. That means that the exact same `dic` object is shared between all instances of `foo`, as well as all instances of *children* of `foo`:

```
>>> b = bar()
('self:', <f.bar object at 0x7f4c31af1950>)
('self', <f.bar object at 0x7f4c31af1950>)
{'bar': 'foo'}
>>> f = foo()
('self:', <f.foo object at 0x7f4c31af1b90>)
>>> f.dic
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'}
>>> b.dic
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'}
>>> f.dic is b.dic
True
>>> bar.dic
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'}
>>> foo.dic
{'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'foo'}
```

If you don't want this behavior, you need to make `dic` an instance variable:

```
class foo(object):   
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic = {}  # Now every instance of `foo` and its children will have their own dic attribute
        print('self:', self)
        self.dic[self.__str__()] = "foo"

    def __go__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'foo'
```

Now you'll get the behavior you expect:

```
>>> from f import foo, bar
>>> b = bar()
('self:', <f.bar object at 0x7f569172d8d0>)
('self', <f.bar object at 0x7f569172d8d0>)
{'bar': 'foo'}
>>> f = foo()
('self:', <f.foo object at 0x7f569172db50>)
>>> f.dic
{'foo': 'foo'}
>>> b.dic
{'bar': 'foo'}
>>> f.dic is b.dic
False
>>> foo.dic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'foo' has no attribute 'dic'
>>> bar.dic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'bar' has no attribute 'dic'
```

The official documentation [even specifically calls out this exact mistake](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables):

> As discussed in A Word About Names and Objects, shared data can have
>   possibly surprising effects with involving mutable objects such as
>   lists and dictionaries. For example, the tricks list in the following
>   code should not be used as a class variable because just a single list
>   would be shared by all Dog instances:
>
> ```
> class Dog:
>
>     tricks = []             # mistaken use of a class variable
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self.name = name
>
>     def add_trick(self, trick):
>         self.tricks.append(trick)
>
> >>> d = Dog('Fido')
> >>> e = Dog('Buddy')
> >>> d.add_trick('roll over')
> >>> e.add_trick('play dead')
> >>> d.tricks                # unexpectedly shared by all dogs
> ['roll over', 'play dead']
> ```
>
> Correct design of the class should use an instance variable instead:
>
> ```
> class Dog:
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self.name = name
>         self.tricks = []    # creates a new empty list for each dog
>
>     def add_trick(self, trick):
>         self.tricks.append(trick)
>
> >>> d = Dog('Fido')
> >>> e = Dog('Buddy')
> >>> d.add_trick('roll over')
> >>> e.add_trick('play dead')
> >>> d.tricks ['roll over']
> >>> e.tricks ['play dead']
> ['roll over', 'play dead']
> ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replying. However, please refer to my test case 2, which indicates it is not a class property. (Comment others !!!)

Comment: @WangYi I'm not sure what you mean. Test case two works as expected because you're not creating an instance of `foo` before you call `bar`. If you were to create an instance of `foo` before hand, `dic` would contain both `foo` and `bar`. `dic` is absolutely a class attribute. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) for more information.

Comment: I have added comments in codes. you should not test three cases simultaneously. This is what I meant @dano

Comment: @WangYi That's how I tested it. The answer doesn't change; `dic` is a class attribute shared among all instances of `foo` and its children. In test case 1 and 3, you're creating instance of both `foo` and `bar`, so `dic` has an entry for both. In test case 2, you only create an instance of `bar`, so there is only an entry in `dic` for `bar`.

Comment: the identity testing is convincing. I will accept your answer. But it is ridiculous because I didn't use '@static' decorator, isn't it? @dano

Comment: @WangYi The `@staticmethod `decorator (there is no `@static` decorator in the language) is only used for methods, not attributes. Any attribute defined in the body of a class, instead of inside an instance method, is always created at class scope. This is all documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Answer (score 0):

@Dano 's testing is reasonable but here comes new situation. Then reason why I test in such a way, is that I want readable data shared among the whole objects of the same class but not writable results shared among different classes (mother class, sub class etc):

I wrote classes in such a way:

```
class mother(object):

param = {'mother':metadata} #mutable

    def __init__():
        bla bla bla
**********************
        position   = self.position[self.__name__()] #for dynamic purpose
        clsmembers = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__], inspect.isclass)
        for k in self.hierarchicalkeys[position:]:
            for m in clsmembers:
                if k == m[0]:
                    self.hierarchicalchain.append(m[1])
                    break #jump out of the most inner loop
**********************

class monther'son(mother):

param = {"monther'son":metadata} #mutable
     bla bla bla

class mother'son'son(mother'son):

param = {"mother'son'son":metadata} #mutable
     bla bla bla
```

## Here is my running result I got in pydev:

```
m: [<class '__main__.MonthData'>, <class '__main__.DayData'>, <class '__main__.HourData'>]
d: [<class '__main__.DayData'>, <class '__main__.HourData'>]
```

I used the same technique in my question I posted. So what is the difference? When you passed "self" in subclass, it will refer to subclass object itself! That means if you overwrite the param in subclass, you will end up with different param! @dano.

```
self.position is m.position
False
```

So do overwrite the param in subclass! This is the key to share readable data without concerning about inheritance overwritten problem in python!